# using nasm directive section vstart=0 make something wrong

Tags: nasm, boot, directive

I can assemble with and without

```
section my_main vstart=0
```

but with it, the bochs emulator claim that there is no bootable disk.

```
    jmp $


    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55
    db 0xaa
```

without it, bochs claim nothing.

```
section my_main vstart=0
here:
    %include 'main.s'

    times 1474560 - ($-$$) db 0
```

how can I change 
label "here" from 512 to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`section my_main vstart=N` change value of `$` and `$$`

Thus `times` directive was affected by the calculated value.

As a result, the floppy image size changed.

And unable to boot.

(Because the size of floppy image does not meet the 1474560 agreement.)

Without `vstart` directive, the size will be 1474560.

But with the `vstart` directive, the image file size becomes 1474560 + 512.

Thus bochs claim to boot.

I solved the problem by changing

```
times 1474560 - ($-$$) db 0
```

to

```
times 1474560 - ($-$$) - loader_size db 0
```

I define `loader_size` right below boot signature.

```
jmp $


    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55
    db 0xaa

%define loader_size ($-$$)
```

And it works as expected!